# Default focused button of yes/no MessageBox

Tags: vb.net, focus, messagebox

How can I achieve this? Didn't find anything useful in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.8)

I want to do this because of a pop-up "Are you really sure to want to remove [...]" and I want the "No" button to be preselected in case the user miss-click on his enter key.

Comment: It's good that you went to the documentation but bad that you ignored the information right in front of you. You didn't wonder what all those parameters of type `MessageBoxDefaultButton` might have been for? If you're looking for information about default buttons, that seems an obvious clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer your are looking for is MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
    "Are you sure ....?",
    "Question",
    buttons,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2
);
```

Comment: Thank you I was sure there was a way to access these buttons directly!

Comment: @AxelCarré The way to thank people on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer. To accept an answer click the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Comment: I know but it forces me to come back after 10 min and I always forget.